# Adding docker to django project: no such file or directory

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to add docker support to an already existing django project. I have a `Dockerfile`, a `docker-compose`, and a `gunicorn.sh` which I use as a script to launch the whole things. That script works fine when I run it from my shell.

When I run:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: for intranet_django_1  Cannot start service django: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"/srv/gunicorn.sh\": stat /srv/gunicorn.sh: no such file or directory"
```

*What the hell am I doing wrong?*

I am very much a docker n00b so any explanation would be most welcome.

---

The `Dockerfile` looks like so:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV DB_NAME unstable_intranet_django
ENV DB_USER django
ENV DB_PASSWORD ookookEEK
ENV DB_HOST db
ENV DB_PORT 3306
RUN groupadd -r django
RUN useradd -r -g django django
COPY ./requirements/requierments.txt /srv/
RUN pip install -U pip
RUN pip install -r /srv/requierments.txt
COPY ./intranet_site/ /srv
RUN chmod a+rx /srv/gunicorn.sh
RUN chown -R django:django /srv/
USER django
WORKDIR /srv
```

I am well aware that the passwords should not be set here and that a permanent volume with a file containing them is probably the best way to deal with it. However, I kinda want something working instead of spending hours fiddling with things and not being able to see *anything* run…

The `docker-compose.yml` looks like:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=fubar
      - MYSQL_USER=django
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=ookookEEK
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=unstable_intranet_django
  django:
    build: .
    command: /srv/gunicorn.sh
    volumes:
      - .:/srv
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Finally, the `gunicorn.sh` file is:

```
#!/bin/bash
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Check if the database is alive or not.
python << END
from MySQLdb import Error
from MySQLdb import connect
from sys import exit
from time import sleep

retry=0
while True:
    try:
        conn = connect(db="$DB_NAME",
                       user="$DB_USER",
                       password="$DB_PASSWORD",
                       host="$DB_HOST",
                       port=$DB_PORT)
        print("✔ DB $DB_NAME on $DB_HOST:$DB_PORT is up.")
        break
    except Error as err:
        snooze = retry / 10.0
        print("✖ DB $DB_NAME on $DB_HOST:$DB_PORT is unavailable "
              "→ sleeping for {}…".format(snooze))
        sleep(snooze)
        retry += 1
exit(0)
END

# Set up log file.
log="./gunicorn.log"
date > ${log}

# Collectstatic
echo "Collecting static files." | tee -a ${log}
python manage.py collectstatic -v 3 --noinput >> ${log}

# Migrate database
echo "Doing database migration." | tee -a ${log}
python manage.py migrate -v 3 >> ${log}

# New shiny modern hip way:
echo "Running Gunicorn on ${HOSTNAME} …" | tee -a ${log}
gunicorn -b ${HOSTNAME}:8000 -w 2 intranet_site.wsgi | tee -a ${log}
```

To make things stranger:

```
; docker run -it intranet_web /bin/bash                                                                               
django@ce7f641cc1c7:/srv$ ls -l gunicorn.sh                                     
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 django django 1677 Jun  2 07:51 gunicorn.sh                       
django@ce7f641cc1c7:/srv$ ./gunicorn.sh                                         
✖ DB unstable_intranet_django on 127.0.0.1:3306 is unavailable → sleeping for 0.0…
```

So running the script from the containers seems to work just fine…

Comment: I think `COPY ./intranet_site/ /srv` should have a trailing backslash `COPY ./intranet_site/ /srv/`

Comment: Try `RUN chmod a+rx /srv/intranet_site/gunicorn.sh` instead of `RUN chmod a+rx /srv/gunicorn.sh`

Comment: `ADD . /srv/` instead of `COPY ./intranet_site/ /srv`

Comment: If it works running the container, try to check it from compose `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run django /bin/bash`. It sounds weird, but it's not the same running docker directly than using compose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should have:

`ADD . /srv/` instead of `COPY ./intranet_site/ /srv`

because `ADD . /srv/` adds *all* the content of the directory *in which* you have the `Dockerfile` to the `srv` folder from container. So the `COPY`/`ADD` command should be used *in* the folder that contains the `Dockerfile`. And I suppose your `Dockerfile` is in this root directory of the project (alongside `docker-compose.yml` and `gunicorn.sh`).

You could also use `COPY . /srv/` with the same effect.

Comment: Part of the problem is that the docker files were one directory above. I thought I could use paths but clearly not. Very nice clear explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Suspect the path shouldn't have a leading `.`:

```
command: /srv/gunicorn.sh
```

Comment: Sorry. It was a typo. But changing that makes no difference as I get the same error.